# Sending data to nat user over c#

Tags: c#, tcp, file-transfer, nat

How can i send data from server to nat users? I have own implementation for transfer data by tcp/ip but it work only between computers with public ip address.

I hear about udp but i dont know it is only way to do this?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Sending data to nat user over c#

Comment: Most solutions involve both clients connecting to a public server, and the data exchange being brokered through there.  UDP is no magic to breaking NAT.

Comment: I want connect server(public ip) with client(over nat).

Comment: You really can't do that cleanly through NAT in many cases.  You will need the client to establish the connection (C->S) and then connect the two users up at the server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to forward the TCP port you're using on the target routers. E.g. on public IP  70.1.1.33 there is an guy with a local IP address of 192.168.1.103. When you want to connect to that one, the guy on 70.1.1.33 has to forward the port (e.g. 1953) on his/her router to the local address 192.168.1.103.

How this is done varies heavily, depending on the router manufacturer. But google will help you out. You can find more information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translator)

This question could contain your answer: [How do I make a TCP server work behind a router (NAT) without any redirection configuration needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511562/how-do-i-make-a-tcp-server-work-behind-a-router-nat-without-any-redirection-co?rq=1)

Comment: Hmmm... it is weak solution for me, i know it will work but if client changes localization he stop receiving data from server, i want create something like dropbox, and i must be able to connect to server from any localisation.

Comment: Well, then you have to make things more complicated. Dropbox uses a server to synchronize, so all participants are **clients**. So you'd have to use a server to negotiate connections. Another solution would be UPNP, but I'd strongly advise against that. VPN would be another workaround. There is just no way to connect otherwise.

Comment: Many enterprises block UPNP anyway, so it would be a solution for some people but not a lot.

Comment: So i see i have problem, i can always send this data by http server, but it is not good solution for me.

Comment: Thanks, i'm reading this and i see that this guy has both machines(client and server) over nat, i have only one machine(client).

Comment: Well.. whatever you do, you can't circument the basic problem, that multiple clients can be behind a NAT. You'll have to use either a negotiating server or use portforwarding in one form or another. Sorry, but that's just the way it is. Downvoting me for it is shooting the messenger.