# Python reverse proxy connection

Tags: python, tcp, proxy

[image]

I'm trying to make a HTTP/S proxy server work without having to manually port forward.

- Machine A has installed a proxy server
- Machine A is behind a NAT (or a router with firewall).
- Machine B tries to browse internet through Machine A proxy.
- Machine B isn't behind a NAT.
- Both machines know each other before any connection is made.
- In a full scale, there would be multiple Machine A but **only one Machine B**.

Machine A shouldn't need to configure anything on the router.

I have thought about using uPnP, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1511603/80766), but as the title of this question, I wanted to know if it would be possible to invert the roles of the machines.

Instead of Machine B initiating a connection, Machine A will do it. So Machine A would be the client and Machine B would be the server. Remember Machine A knows the IP address of Machine B beforehand.

In this scenario, Machine A would still function as a proxy, but having the role of the *client* in a standard TCP connection.

I understand this would need a custom-made proxy server, which is no problem since the proxy server is implemented in `python` and I have access to the source, and can modify it.

- Will this be compatible with normal HTTP/S proxy? Specifically I will be using `python` `requests` on Machine B.
- Does this method have a name? Researching for *inverse* or *reverse* lands me on *reverse proxy* which AFAIK doesn't have anything to do with what I'm trying to accomplish.
- Is there something I'm missing? Or an alternative solution? (besides uPnP)

Comment: why you want write on your own? there are numbers of proxy choices.

Comment: I don't want to write my own. If there's a solution that works that's fine with me.

Answer (score 1):

a simple solution is OpenSSH port forwarding.

first forward port 20000 on "Machine B" to port 10000 on "Machine A" with remote port forwarding:

```
[A]$ ssh -N -R 20000:localhost:10000 Machine_B
```

then setup a tunnel on port 10000 on "Machine A" with dynamic port forwarding:

```
[A]$ ssh -N -D 10000 localhost
```

now you can use 127.0.0.1:20000 as a SOCKS5 proxy on "Machine B":

```
[B]$ curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:20000 example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

it called "Reverse", you need [shootback](https://github.com/aploium/shootback) to reverse TCP tunnel, it work like OpenSSH port forwarding and Socks5 proxy server like [pysocks](https://github.com/fengyouchao/pysocks) it better than HTTP/S proxy server.

on MachineB (You)

```
python3 master.py -m 0.0.0.0:10000 -c 0.0.0.0:10800
```

on MachineA (Remote)

```
python socks5.py start --port=1080
python slaver.py -m <MachineA_IP>:10000 -t 127.0.0.1:1080
```

now on MachineB you can set browser or any app to socks5

```
localhost:10800
```